# when i clicked the button '=', there's nothing happen

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make a simple calculator with javascript, but when i clicked the button '=' the result didn't appear.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Kalkulator Sederhana</h1>
            <input type="text" name="angkapertama" placeholder="Angka Pertama" id="angkapertama">
            <input type="text" name="angkakedua" placeholder="Angka Kedua" id="angkakedua">
        <button id="hasil" onclick="tambah">=</button>

        <h2 id="hsl"></h2>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById('angkapertama').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('angkakedua').value;
            var c = document.getElementById('hasil');
            c.addEventListener('click', tambah, false);

            function tambah() {
                return a + b;
                document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = tambah; 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're `return`ing from your function before updating the DOM....

Comment: And your variables `a` and `b`, will always contain the value the inputs had, when `var a = ...` ran. They won't update with changing the textfields. And, the values contain Strings, not numbers. `string + string` is a string-concatenation, not a numeric addition.

Answer (score 2):

A number of problems with this

1) Collecting the input values from the textboxes before the user has had chance to type anything into them. You need to do that inside the event handler.

2) An inline event attribute (which was wrongly defined without the `()` anyway) *and* an eventlistener added in code. Only one is needed. The eventListener is generally considered the better way, e.g. for code maintainability and visibility.

3) Treating the values as strings and not numbers (e.g. if the code had otherwise been working, "4" + "4" would have returned "44"!)

4) returning from your tambah() function before the line which actually displayed the result. `return` returns from a function, it's not just for getting the result of a calculation.

This version corrects all those errors. You can run it to test it out:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('hasil');
c.addEventListener('click', tambah, false);

function tambah() {
  var a = document.getElementById('angkapertama').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('angkakedua').value;
  var sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
  document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<h1> Kalkulator Sederhana</h1>
<input type="text" name="angkapertama" placeholder="Angka Pertama" id="angkapertama">
<input type="text" name="angkakedua" placeholder="Angka Kedua" id="angkakedua">
<button id="hasil">=</button>

<h2 id="hsl"></h2>
```

Comment: @Mavisa9 no problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to upvote it and/or mark as the accepted answer - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Simple example

```js
var c = document.getElementById('hasil');
c.addEventListener('click', tambah, false);

function tambah() {
    var a = document.getElementById('angkapertama').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('angkakedua').value;
  
    var sum = Number(a) + Number(b); //or
    // var sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
    document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = sum;
    console.log(sum)
 }
```

```html
<h1> Kalkulator Sederhana</h1>
<input type="text" name="angkapertama" placeholder="Angka Pertama" id="angkapertama">
<input type="text" name="angkakedua" placeholder="Angka Kedua" id="angkakedua">
<button id="hasil">=</button>

<h2 id="hsl"></h2>
```

> However, the addEventListener() function, despite it’s the standard, just doesn’t work in old browsers (Internet Explorer below version 9), and this is another big difference. If you need to support these ancient browsers, you should follow the `onclick` way.

HTML:

```
<button id="hasil" onclick="tambah()">=</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function tambah() {
    var a = document.getElementById('angkapertama').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('angkakedua').value;

    var sum = Number(a) + Number(b); //or
    // var sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
    document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = sum;
    console.log(sum)
 }
```

content source [here](https://www.simonewebdesign.it/onclick-vs-addeventlistener/)

Comment: `var c = document.getElementById('hasil');` is redundant. In the original code `c` was used to create an unobstrusive event listener. You're using an inline event attribute (which btw is considered an outdated practise because it creates less readable/maintainable/discoverable code) so you don't need it. Also a better quality answer would explain the reason for all the various changes. It seems clear the OP did not understand the code sufficiently to fix the issues, so explaining what you did aids OP's learning instead of just spoon-feeding a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things incorrect with your code.

When you return a + b, there's no code executed after that return statement.

I've changed the code slightly, the vars a and b are now defined inside the function, and also made sure to use `parseInt` on your a and b - otherwise they would end up being concatenated as strings (meaning 1 + 2 would be 12 - wrong!)

```js
var c = document.getElementById('hasil');
c.addEventListener('click', tambah);

function tambah() 
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('angkapertama').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('angkakedua').value);
    var result = a + b;
    document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = result; 
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Kalkulator Sederhana</h1>
            <input type="text" name="angkapertama" placeholder="Angka Pertama" id="angkapertama">
            <input type="text" name="angkakedua" placeholder="Angka Kedua" id="angkakedua">
        <button id="hasil">=</button>

        <h2 id="hsl">answer here</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1> Kalkulator Sederhana</h1>
                <input type="text" name="angkapertama" placeholder="Angka Pertama" id="angkapertama">
                <input type="text" name="angkakedua" placeholder="Angka Kedua" id="angkakedua">
            <button id="hasil" onclick="tambah()">=</button>

            <h2 id="hsl"></h2>

            <script>
                var a = document.getElementById('angkapertama').value;
                var b = document.getElementById('angkakedua').value;
                var c = document.getElementById('hasil');
                c.addEventListener('click', tambah, false);

                function tambah() {
                    var sum = a + b;
                    document.getElementById("hsl").innerHTML = sum; 
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A better answer would explain _why_. And it shouldn't need an inline event attribute _and_ an eventlistener declared in the code. The unobstrusive eventlistener would be the better choice. Inline event handlers are generally considered to be bad practise these days.

Comment: @Mavisa9 that's because it doesn't address all the issues. In fact it changes the one thing that didn't 100% need changing (really it just needed removing completely). Check my answer.